# Django admin URL query string "OR". Is it possible?

Tags: django, query-string, admin

I love being able to write quick and dirty query strings right into the URL of the Django admin.  Like: `/admin/myapp/mymodel/?pub_date__year=2011`

AND statements are just as easy: `/admin/myapp/mymodel/?pub_date__year=2011&author=Jim`

I'm wondering if it's possible to issue an 'OR' statement via the URL.  Anyone heard of such functionality?

Comment: Well, don't ever upgrade Django, then. The ability to do that was removed in 1.2, I think. Django will now only let you add query strings to the URL that can directly translate to items in `list_filter`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django < 1.4 doesn't support OR queries. Sometimes it is possible to translate OR queries to __in - queries which are supported (they are equivalent to OR queries but only for single field values).

You can also upgrade to django development version: it has more versatile list_filter implementation (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev//ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter ) which can be used for providing advanced admin filters (including OR-queries).

Comment: What about using the ...objects.filter(Q(some_field=some_val) | Q(some_other_field=some_val))? That works in earlier versions, but maybe the question is more directed at an admin feature. The original question, though, is how to add logical OR statements to the URL query string, which is not possible.

Comment: OR queries are possible for single fields: `color__in=red,blue` in URL is equal to `Q(color='red') | Q(color='blue')`. For more complex queries advanced admin hacking or django 1.4 is necessary.

Comment: @MikhailKorobov, You're not answering his question. You mention that Django 1.4 can do this, but you don't state how and link to a the admin doc page that doesn't seem to state anything about it...

Comment: @Cerin, I didn't explain in details how to do this in django 1.4 because django 1.4 was released March 23, 2012 and my answer is from November 2011, so I believe it was useful at that time. And there are examples how to create an arbitrary list filter in the linked admin doc page, the anchor is correct. Take a look at SimpleListFilter example: it is possible to put any ORM expression to "queryset" method and to specify how to handle the URLs in "lookups" method.

Answer (score 5):

The & is not a logical AND, even though it seems to be acting that way in your case. I'm pretty certain there is no way to create a logical OR in the GET query string.

Comment: is this true in 2015? You could add your own syntax to solve the problem, but is there a build-in way?